# Where are .NET's internal resource strings stored

Tags: c#, .net

I'm decompiling some .NET code for diagnosing an issue but the object is very large. To that end, I've been trying to see where .NET would raise the error I'm looking for by resource string as the exception type is fairly generic but the error message is specific to ultimate issue I'm looking into.

Decompiling the code, I see that it uses a string resource manager to pull out the text but without being able to match the resource key to the text, I cannot trace from the error message to the point in decompiled code.

E.g., exceptions are generated like the following in the decompiled code:

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", SR.GetString("net_io_timeout_use_ge_zero"));
```

Where would I find the .NET's localized error text and associated resource key (e.g. `"net_io_timeout_use_ge_zero"`)?

I've tried using ResHacker on `System.dll` and `System.Net.dll` (the assembly with the object I'm investigating) but both of these yield nothing. Likewise, while there's a culture subfolder of `en-US` under `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and the 64 equivalent but these don't show any text bar the assembly details and some icons in the `System.dll`

Comment: If your are using ILSpy, then you can find [`Resources` node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp1g8.png) right inside assembly node.

Comment: @PetSerAl, boom, spot on. Put that out as an answer and I'll mark it as such :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)'s answer (if he posts one, I'll mark it as such) but to find the resource strings you can use ILSpy to load up the assembly and the resources can be found on the `Resources` node like so;

[image: Resources Node]

Going further, while ILSpy does list the resources, it doesn't provide a direct way to search for them. Saving saves out the compiled details which are not easily readable (there's a github request for this). In the meantime, you can select the contents the grid by selecting a single item, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the grid to the clipboard. From there you can paste into the likes of Excel or Notepad and search for the text you need.